# create new variable based on matches in groups within groups

Tags: r

I have a dataset that includes participants who report to a clinic at two time points (episode 1 and episode 2).

During the two visits, they are checked two see the number of strains of parasites infecting them, i.e.

```
df_1 <- structure(list(PID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), parasite = c("parasite_1", 
"parasite_2", "parasite_1", "parasite_1", "parasite_2", "parasite_3", 
"parasite_4", "parasite_5"), episode = c("first_episode", "first_episode", 
"second_episode", "first_episode", "first_episode", "first_episode", 
"second_episode", "second_episode")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

From the dataset:

patient 1 harbours 2 parasites during their first visit (parasite 1 and 2), but during their second visit they harbour only 1 parasite (parasite 1) and it matches one of the parasites from the first episode.

patient 2 harbours 3 parasites during their first visit (parasite 1, 2 and 3), but during their second visit they harbour 2 parasites (parasite 4 and 5) and they do not match any of the parasites from the first episode.

I need help with coming up with a script that creates a new variable (infection) and populates it with "same" if during their second episode, a patient presents with a parasite from the first episode and "different" if they present with a parasite that is different from all the parasites in the first episode, i.e.

```
df_2 <- structure(list(PID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), parasite = c("parasite_1", 
"parasite_2", "parasite_1", "parasite_1", "parasite_2", "parasite_3", 
"parasite_4", "parasite_5"), episode = c("first_episode", "first_episode", 
"second_episode", "first_episode", "first_episode", "first_episode", 
"second_episode", "second_episode"), infeciton = c("same", "same", 
"same", "different", "different", "different", "different", "different"
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Hi, Oka. I have edited the last bit to include the question.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the nicest way but the logic should be understandable:

```
patients <- unique(df_1$PID)
df_3 <- df_1
df_3$infection <- NA
for (patient in patients){

  # getting your parasites into two lists
  first <- df_1[which(df_1$PID == patient & df_1$episode == "first_episode"), ]
  first <- first$parasite
  second <- df_1[which(df_1$PID == patient & df_1$episode == "second_episode"), ]
  second <- second$parasite

  # setting the infection 
  infection <- "different"
  for (parasite in second){
    if (parasite %in% first) {infection <- "same"}
    else {next}
  }
  df_3[which(df_3$PID == patient), "infection"] <- infection
}


# correcting the typo in colname in df_2:
df_2$infection <- df_2$infeciton
df_2 <- df_2[c("PID",   "parasite", "episode", "infection")]

# comparing the df_2 and df_3
identical(df_2, df_3)
# [1] TRUE
```